# How to handle expired assets/content when user has direct URL

Tags: redirect, urls, seo

An E-Commerce site has PDF coupons that expire after a certain date.  What is the best way to handle them?  I've heard allowing 404's aren't great for SEO and 301 redirects can clog up the .htaccess.

There is already a landing page generated through internal links if a coupon is expired, so ideally I would like a way to capture requests to expired assets and redirect to that page.

I'm curious, what ways are there to handle this?

Comment: it's probably easier to expire them if you don't allow direct access in the first place. have a script that accepts a coupon id, check if id is valid, serve associated file or custom error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these pdfs all in a sub-directory somewhere? You could add an .htaccess file to your sub-directory root then put this as the top line.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/your404page
```

This would make it easier to manage and keep it separate from your main htaccess file.

Comment: While that would work, I'm curious if there is a way to do this more programmatically so the client doesn't have to reach out to me every month a coupon list expires.  Edit: To answer your initial question, they are in the normal uploads directory but have a naming convention of "Print-coupon-brand.pdf", which I could throw a wildcard on.

Comment: Maybe have a cron job write an htaccess each month to those folders and hide coupons following naming convention?

Comment: What about just looking at the URL that caused the 404 and check for "Print-coupon-" or something.  You could serve up a unique 404 message or redirect to a different template altogether.  You could do this all within 404.php. Just thinking of ideas :)

Comment: As far as SEO is concerned, wouldn't a 301 be better?

Comment: I would think so, you could just redirect to your landing page you have setup or maybe even the latest coupon?

Comment: Are you using WooCommerce?  They have built in coupon code support.